# Rock - Paper - Scissors: How to add scoring?

Tags: c#

(I tried all kind of combinations and looked it up but most solutions were in other languages like python.)

I'm trying to make a simple rock paper scissors game in C# with ASP.NET MVC where I can add the score. The first one (computer vs. player) to reach score 10 wins the game. I also want to add to option where you can Bet for more than 1 point.

I made the game with simple nested if statements and have added scoring in between. Problem is that when I press play (send to server..) to go again, he resets the score and starts again. How do I fix this?

The second question is: how I can add a betting system that I implement in the score? Just typing

> vScoreUser += (Bet * 1);

doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code of my class:

```
    public class BladSteenSchaar
    {
    //Fields       
    private string vChoice;
    private int vChoiceComputer;
    private string vResult;
    Random vRandom = new Random();

    //Properties 
    public string Choice
    {
        get { return vChoice; }
        set 
        { 
            vChoice = value; 

            //Spel opstarten
            this.GeefResult();
        }
    }        
    public int ChoiceComputer
    {
        get { return vChoiceComputer; }
        //set { vChoiceComputer = value; }
    }
    public int Bet { get; set; }
    public string Result
    {
        get { return vResult; }
        //set { vResult = value; }
    }

    private int vScoreUser;

    public int ScoreUser
    {
        get { return vScoreUser; }
        set { vScoreUser = value; }
    }
    private int vScoreComputer;

    public int ScoreComputer
    {
        get { return vScoreComputer; }
        set { vScoreComputer = value; }
    }


    //Methods
    public void GeefResult() 
    { 
        //Vars

        //Generate random choice where: 0 = Rock, 1 = Paper en 2 = Siccors)            
        vChoiceComputer = vRandom.Next(0, 3);

        //Nested if statements met vResult als output
        if (Choice == "Rock")
        {
            if (vChoiceComputer == 0) //Rock
            {
                vResult = "Draw!";                   
            }
            else if (vChoiceComputer == 1) //Paper
            {
                vResult = "U lost!";
                vScoreComputer = vScoreComputer + 1;
            }
            else if (vChoiceComputer == 2) //Siccors
            {
                vResult = "U won!";
                vScoreUser = vScoreUser + 1;
            }   
        }
        else if (Choice == "Paper")
        {
            if (vChoiceComputer == 0) //Rock
            {
                vResult = "U won!";
                vScoreUser = vScoreUser + 1;
            }
            else if (vChoiceComputer == 1) //Paper
            {
                vResult = "Draw!";
            }
            else if (vChoiceComputer == 2) //Siccors
            {
                vResult = "U lost!";
                vScoreComputer = vScoreComputer + 1;
            }    
        }
        else if (Choice == "Siccors")
        {
            if (vChoiceComputer == 0) //Rock
            {
                vResult = "U lost!";
                vScoreComputer = vScoreComputer + 1;
            }
            else if (vChoiceComputer == 1) //Paper
            {                   
                vResult = "U won!";
                vScoreUser = vScoreUser + 1;
            }
            else if (vChoiceComputer == 2) //Siccors
            {
                vResult = "Draw!";
            }
        }

    }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Oef127()
    {
        //Default-object
        BladSteenSchaar vBladSteenSchaar = new BladSteenSchaar();
        vBladSteenSchaar.Bet = 1;

        //Show
        return View(vBladSteenSchaar);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Oef127(BladSteenSchaar vBladSteenSchaar)
    {


        //Show
        return View(vBladSteenSchaar);
    }
```

HTML/CSS:

```
@model Project_CS.Classes.BladSteenSchaar

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Oef127";
}

<style>

form {
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
    width: 500px;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

</style>

<form method="post">

<h2>Rock - Paper - Siccors!</h2>
<hr />

Make your Choice: <br/>
<input type="radio" name="Choice" value="Rock">Rock
<br />
<input type="radio" name="Choice" value="Paper">Paper
<br />
<input type="radio" name="Choice" value="Siccors">Siccors
<br />

<br/>
Do you want to play for 1, 2 or 3 points?
<br/>
<input type="text" name="Bet" value="@Model.Bet" />

<hr/>
<input type="submit" value="Send to Server!" />

<br/>

</form>

<h3>Result:</h3>

@Model.Result

<br /><br />

<b>Current score:</b> <br />

<table>
<tr>
    <td>Player</td>
    <td>Computer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Model.ScoreUser</td>
    <td>@Model.ScoreComputer</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you can spot any other mistakes, please let me know.

Comment: send to server? can you elaborate? some web services platform will create a new class for each connection, so the count will be reset.

Comment: Confirm MVC.NET creates new Controller object on each request. If you want a state, you should consider create singleton class (better by using DI), or save state in the DB

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Sorry, very new to all this.
I'll add what I have in my controller and as html/css in start post.

How would I create a singeton class and what is DI? Can't use databases yet... :x

Comment: Try debug your method marked with HttpPost attribute and see what you have in the vBladSteenSchaar argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the set of this property

```
 public string Choice
    {
        get { return vChoice; }
        set 
        { 
            vChoice = value; 

            //Spel opstarten
            this.GeefResult();
        }
    }
```

every time that you set a Choice you perform `GeefResult` function. Maybe in this function you initialize something to 0 and every choiche it is resetted. Try adding score information as property in `BladSteenSchaar` class. In this way you will be able to store score information for each instance of `BladSteenSchaar` class.

Comment: I was looking for that but can't seem to find any solution. Would it matter where I perform GeefResult? Putting it in my httppost method won't help without adding that scoring information.

Comment: are you sure that you are calling the right `Oef127` function? Try to debug the httpost marked method and let me know if the call arrives there. Maybe you are calling the first one that create a new instance of the class